# when press on the button and then start drawing the button also copy in on the panel

Tags: java, swing

I have two `JPanel`s. The first one contains `JButton`s and in the second simply we can draw on with the **Mouse**. The problem is when I click on the `JButton` and start drawing the `JButton` also draw in on the `JPanel`. Please do provide me, with some direction, as to where I am not looking at ?

---

> main class

```
public class LabelDemo extends JFrame {

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    painter p2 = new painter();
    JButton red = new JButton("red");
    JButton blue = new JButton(" blue ");
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Label");
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("image/YouTube.png");

    public LabelDemo() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.gray));
        //jbt1.setIcon(icon);

        p1.add(red);
        p1.add(blue);
        lbl.setOpaque(true);
        lbl.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        p1.add(lbl);
        p1.setBounds(20, 30, 40, 78);
        add(p1,BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(p2,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        LabelDemo frame = new LabelDemo();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(700, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);              
    }
}
```

> innr class

```
class painter extends JPanel  {

    int x , y;
    boolean isPresed = false;

    public void setPainter(int x , int y) {    
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public painter() {

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {                   
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                isPresed = true;
                setPainter(e.getX(),e.getY());
                repaint(); 
            }   
        });
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Color randomColor = Color.getHSBColor( (float)Math.random(), 1.0F, 1.0F );
        if(isPresed){                       
            g.setColor(randomColor);
            g.fillOval(x-5, y-5, 10, 10);
        }
    }
}//end of painter
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to upload the source code but I could not. I do not know how to upload

Comment: You can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12019996/edit) (link below your question) and copy the relevant code directly in your question.

Comment: Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because... this is what i got

Comment: i do that ok this the inner class

Comment: What is wrong with the default font? Please don't blow up the text if it isn't needed.

Comment: @DanielHailemichael : Please do have a look at the code formatted by me. Either I had deleted the `ActionListener` part for `LabelDemo` class. Please do rectify that, for that my apologies :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as I understood you want to get rid of panel on east (p1 panel) when clicking red or blue button:

```
package stack;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class LabelDemo extends JFrame {
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    Painter p2 = new Painter();
    JButton red = new JButton("red");
    JButton blue = new JButton(" blue ");
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Label");
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("image/YouTube.png");
    public LabelDemo() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.gray));
//      jbt1.setIcon(icon);
        p2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,400));
        p1.add(red);
        p1.add(blue);
        lbl.setOpaque(true);
        lbl.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        p1.add(lbl);
        p1.setBounds(20, 30, 40, 78);
        add(p1,BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(p2,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        red.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            remove(p1);
            repaint();
            revalidate();
        }
    });
    blue.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            remove(p1);
            repaint();
            revalidate();
        }
    });
}


    public static void main(String[] args){
       LabelDemo frame = new LabelDemo();
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.pack();   
       frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
class Painter extends JPanel  {
    int x , y;
    boolean isPresed = false;
     public void setPainter(int x , int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
     public Painter() {

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            isPresed = true;
            setPainter(e.getX(),e.getY());
            repaint(); 
        }   
    });
}

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Color randomColor = Color.getHSBColor( (float)Math.random(), 1.0F, 1.0F );
    if(isPresed){   

        g.setColor(randomColor);
        g.fillOval(x-5, y-5, 10, 10);
    }
    }
}//end of painter
```

Also don't call setSize() method call pack() and setPreferredSize(), I was personaly criticized a few times because of that. Just an annotation.

Comment: I still can not solve the problem, could you please refer to my specific source code?
  I do not want the button disappears ...

Comment: And what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

In your `painter` pane's `paintComponent` method, you really should call `super.paintComponent` first.

Swing reuses the `Graphics`, so its possible to get old content still in its buffer.  If you call `super.paintComponent`, this will clean it up for

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    // Must call super.paintComponent() so the Graphics is updated correctly...
    super.paintComponent();
    Color randomColor = Color.getHSBColor( (float)Math.random(), 1.0F, 1.0F );
    if(isPresed){                       
        g.setColor(randomColor);
        g.fillOval(x-5, y-5, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: when i call super.paintComponent came another problem i can not drawing with a mouse on the panel because the super.paintComponentwill clean it

Comment: Call it first, before you do your painting

Comment: so you say i need to call it in the mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)?

Comment: @DanielHailemichael No - you need to call it from within `paintComponent` before you do any custom painting. See update

Comment: cause i don't want remove all the dawn in the panel (p2)...
i just to do something like MS Painter....

Comment: @danielHailemichael, then you've seen what happens when you don't. If you want to reapply whats been drawn, you have two choices. Either paint to a backing buffer/image OR you reapply all the painting effects on every repaint. The Graphics is a shared resource